# Function that worked before has stopped working

Tags: c++

Essentially, the code is meant to validate, find the manufacture origin, and manufacture date of a vehicle using the VIN number. I had written the "valid" function first and after it worked I moved onto the "origin" and "year" functions. Once they worked, I tested everything together and suddenly the "valid" function would return a "true" value even when it wasn't supposed to. I've tried to rewrite it, but as far as I can tell, only the if statement regarding length and the for loop actually work. What I don't understand is why it's not working correctly.

To go into more detail, the VIN number must be 17 characters long, must have only digits and uppercase letters, and must exclude the letters "I," "O," "Q," "U," and "Z." Again, the arrangement I had worked, but after writing the subsequent two functions it ceased to return a false value when the above criteria was not met.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I've been over this numerous times and I can't seem to figure out where I'm missing something.

Edit: Added a missing digit to the VIN array.

```
using namespace std;

#include <cstring>
#include<cctype>
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

bool valid(char[]);
void origin(char[], char[]);
int year(char[]);

int main() {

bool validity;

char vin[] = "1FTRW14W84KC76110";
char country[20];

cout << "Testing the VIN " << vin << endl;

validity = valid(vin);

if (validity == true) {
    cout << "\nVIN is valid" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "\nVIN is not vaild." << endl;
}

origin(vin, country);

cout << "Year: " << year(vin) << endl;

return 0;
}

bool valid(char vin[]) {

bool result = false;

long long length = strlen(vin);

if (length == 17) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        if (isalnum(vin[i])) {
            if (isupper(vin[i])) {
                if (vin[i] != 'I' && vin[i] != 'O' && vin[i] != 'Q' && vin[i] != 'U' && vin[i] != 'Z') {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (isdigit(vin[i])) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
}
else {
    result = false;
}

return result;
}

void origin(char vin[], char country[]) {

if (vin[0] >= 'A' && vin[0] <= 'H') {
    strcpy(country, "Africa");
    cout << "Origin: " << country << endl;
}
else if (vin[0] >= 'J' && vin[0] <= 'R') {
    strcpy(country, "Asia");
    cout << "Origin: " << country << endl;
}
else if (vin[0] >= 'S' && vin[0] <= 'Y') {
    strcpy(country, "Europe");
    cout << "Origin: " << country << endl;
}
else if (vin[0] >= '1' && vin[0] <= '5') {
    strcpy(country, "North America");
    cout << "Origin: " << country << endl;
}
else if (vin[0] >= '6' && vin[0] <= '7') {
    strcpy(country, "Oceania");
    cout << "Origin: " << country << endl;
}
else {
    strcpy(country, "South America");
    cout << "Origin: " << country << endl;
    }
}

int year(char vin[]) {

int y;

if (isdigit(vin[9])){
    y = 2000 + (vin[9] - '0');
}
if (vin[9] <= 'M') {
    y = 2010 + (vin[9] - 'A');
}
else{
    y = 1993 + (vin[9] - 'P');
}

return y;
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ the arrangement you had worked? Even if I take out your definitions of `origin` and `year`, I get ["VIN is not valid"](https://godbolt.org/z/41xTaWqzv). And just at a glance, your design looks definitely incorrect. There's no way you should be returning `true` in the middle of your `for` loop, because there's still characters you haven't checked yet that might invalidate the string.

Comment: Your code is a bit strange... do you realize that "return true" and "return false" inside the for loop will stop the loop and terminate the valid function? Perhaps it should be "result = true" and "result = false" respectively.

Comment: Also this code _should_ be saying "VIN is not valid" because the vin you're testing is only 16 characters long.

Comment: To answer Nathan's question, I accidently left a zero off the end of the complete number. I was testing for "O" to see if it would give me a negative result and forget to add the "0" back in.

To answer Sven, I do. I wanted the function to immediately return a false value to result if any of the criteria had been violated. Was there something I missed or added here that I enter or used incorrectly?

Comment: Returning `false` early is perfectly sensible, since as soon as you find an invalid letter you can conclude that the entire string is invalid without checking the rest of it. Returning `true` early is the error. Right now, as long as your string is the right length and the _first_ character is valid, it skips checking the remaining 16.

Comment: Consider using std::string instead of char[]. Your code is just waiting to crash by an out of bound error somewhere.

Comment: The assignment calls for using cstring and to avoid using a string.

Comment: Instead of learning C-with-cout,, why not get a proper modern C++ book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have commented, you are mixing styles of fail checks with pass checks.  It's good to pick one style, and then you can simplify the logic.  Here is an example of all fail checks.

```cpp
bool valid(char vin[])
{
    bool result = false;

    long long length = strlen(vin);

    if (length != 17)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(vin[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (islower(vin[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (vin[i] == 'I' || vin[i] == 'O' || vin[i] == 'Q' || vin[i] == 'U' || vin[i] == 'Z')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The logic can be simplified further still by flipping the `!isupper` into an `islower` and dropping the `isdigit` check entirely

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. I'll remember that in the future.

Comment: @NathanPierson amended as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

As Nathan points out this has never worked.

All the

```
return true;
```

Statements should read

```
result = true; // Continue checking...
```

You are getting bad positives by breaking too early on `return true`.

You tagged this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) so in c++ one would rather be inclined to write it as something like.

```
bool is_valid(std::string vin){
    std::string forbidden = "IOQUZ";

    auto has_forbidden_it = std::find_first_of(vin.begin(), vin.end(), 
                                     forbidden.begin(), forbidden.end());
    if(has_forbidden_it != vin.end()){
       return false;
    }
    if(vin.size() != 17){
        return false;
    }
    for(char ch: vin){
        auto valid_ch = std::isdigit(ch) || std::isupper(ch);
        if(!valid_ch){
            return false;
        }
    }        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Eh. I don't think the `result` variable should be used at all. I think it should `return false;` as soon as it knows it's invalid, and then once it exits the loop it can unconditionally `return true;` without needing to maintain some other variable.

Comment: @NathanPierson That would of course be the next improvement, but then we would be in more of a code-review situation geared to a more or less complete rewrite.

Comment: I'm not sure the asker's code is actually returning false negatives, only false positives.

Comment: @NathanPierson I stand corrected, fixed.